# Erro: Expected End of Statement

Tags: sql, asp

Estou a utilizar o SQL para uma página em ASP clássico e numa parte do código tenho isto:

```
            If (opcao = 1) Then
        If credito > 0 Then
            SQL = "UPDATE FO_Passaportes SET creditoTotal = creditoTotal + " & credito & " WHERE IDPassaporte = " & IDPassaporte & ""
        Else
            SQL = "UPDATE FO_Passaportes SET creditoUsado = creditoUsado + " & Abs(credito) & " WHERE IDPassaporte = " & IDPassaporte & ""
        End If
        End If
        If (opcao = 2) Then
            SQL = "UPDATE FO_Passaportes SET creditoTotal = creditoTotal - " & Abs(credito) & " WHERE IDPassaporte = " & ID Passaporte & ""
        End If
```

Quando executo estou a obter o seguinte erro:

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'
>
> Expected end of statement
>
> /GIP-eP/Formacao/passaportes/gravapassaporte.asp, line 234
>
> SQL = "UPDATE FO_Passaportes SET creditoTotal = creditoTotal - " & Abs(credito) & " WHERE IDPassaporte = " & ID Passaporte & ""----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

O erro está a apontar para a minha ultima query:

```
        If (opcao = 2) Then
        SQL = "UPDATE FO_Passaportes SET creditoTotal = creditoTotal - " & Abs(credito) & " WHERE IDPassaporte = " & ID Passaporte & ""
    End If
```

O que estou a fazer de mal??

Comment: Acredito que não exista aquele espaço em `ID Passaporte`

Comment: @rray Você está certo  Obrigado xD >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um espaço aqui `ID Passaporte`, o certo é `IDPassaporte`.

O código em geral está confuso e pode ser simplificado, o que ajuda identificar mais esses problemas.